# mysql max date help

Tags: mysql

i have

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=74mPrMqE

And need get max date.. i try select id,name,max(date) from tbl group by id,name

But not work :S

thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the field type of date? If it is a varchar or similar the ordering will be different. Try changing it to timestamp or datetime.

Also try enclosing the date with back ticks
select id,name,max(`date`) from tbl group by id,name

this should return

id name date

1 John 9/1/2010 6:55:48 AM

2 Joe 9/1/2009 6:43:52 AM